# Conditional formula with multiple and/or

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want a formula to do the following:

- if C2 is >=55 and D2 is >=30 OR
- C2 is >=60 and D2 is >=20 OR
- C2 is >=62 and D2 is >=5, "yes" ,"no"

Answer (score 4):

```
=IF(OR(AND(C2 >= 55,D2 >= 30),AND(C2 >= 60, D2 >= 20),AND(C2 >= 62,D2 >= 5)),"yes","no")
```

i think i closed all the parens

Comment: You did.